# Style Php contact form mail

Tags: php, forms, contacts

I was wondering how to style the $body =" part so my incomming e-mails are more friendly to read.

I've already tried some stuff like adding  tags or body tags, but it all doesnt seem to work, please help me tackle this annoying problem,

Much regards,

Quincy

```
<?php
                    $name = $_POST['name'];
                    $email = $_POST['email'];
                    $message = $_POST['message'];
                    $from = 'From: info@epicconcepts.nl'; 
                    $to = 'info@epicconcepts.nl'; 
                    $subject = 'Contact formulier bericht';
                    $human = $_POST['human'];

                    $headers = "From: " . strip_tags($_POST['req-email']) . "\r\n";
                    $headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($_POST['req-email']) . "\r\n";
                    $headers .= "CC: quincynorbert@live.nl\r\n";
                    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
                    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

                    $body = "
                    New Mail $name\n $email\n \n $message";

                    if ($_POST['submit']) {
                        if ($name != '' && $email != '') {
                            if ($human == '4') {                 
                                if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
                                echo '<p class="correct-message">Your message has been sent!</p>';
                            } else { 
                                echo '<p class="correct-message">Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
                            } 
                        } else if ($_POST['submit'] && $human != '4') {
                            echo '<p class="correct-message">You answered the anti-spam question incorrectly!</p>';
                        }
                        } else {
                            echo '<p class="correct-message">You need to fill in all required fields!</p>';
                        }
                    }
                ?>
```

Comment: Just add valid html code to $body var?

Comment: What happens when you add tags? Do they have no effect?

Answer (score 0):

If you are just using css styles (like style="correct-message") - this will not work, you should add styles definitions in body too, like this:

```
<style> .correct-message{font-weight:bold; color:red;}</style>
```

Comment: Can you explain any further? maybe an example?

Comment: simple html: `code`$body = "<html><body>New Mail <b>name:</b> $name<br> <b>email:</b> $email<br><br> <p>$message</p> </body></html>";`code`